# google.cloud.spark module not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

While using google cloud dataproc to run a pyspark job. My code tried to do a query on bigquery using pyspark
query = 'select max(col a) from table'
df = spark.read.format('bigquery').load(query)

Comment: Could you add a problem description? This is not clear from your current text.

Comment: here are some links to help you ask -- [ask], [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudDataproc/cloud-dataproc/blob/master/notebooks/python/1.1.%20BigQuery%20Storage%20%26%20Spark%20DataFrames%20-%20Python.ipynb). Here you'll have a example code to do bigquery queries with spark in dataproc.

Comment: I have given bq jar in spark config

Comment: Could you add the error?

Answer (score 0):

You see this error because Dataproc does not include Spark BigQuery connector jar by default, that's why you need to add it to your Spark application if you want to use Spark to process data in BigQuery.

Here is documentation with examples on how to do this for Dataproc Serverless and Dataproc clusters:

- https://cloud.google.com/dataproc-serverless/docs/guides/bigquery-connector-spark-example
- https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/bigquery-connector-spark-example